# Why is cv::VideoCapture crashing for uncompressed videos?

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

I have some standard read-in-the-video code that works in most cases.  However, when I try to read in a frame from a specific set of videos I have, I get an access violation error.  The unique characteristic of these videos is their data rate is over 20,000 kbps, while most compressed videos are under 1000 kbps.  Why is this an issue, and how can I get around it or catch it?

Here is a simple code example:

```
cv::VideoCapture capture;
capture.open(video_filename);

if (!capture.isOpened())
{
    // throw an error
}

cv::Mat frame;
capture >> frame; // crashes here.
```

Comment: What OS do You use? And what kind of crash message do You get?

Comment: I got the exact same problem. Reading an uncompressed video file(.avi) in Windows 7 x64 leads to an access violation. Apparently this is a known bug: http://code.opencv.org/issues/2281

Comment: try ```while(capture.read(frame)) { ......... }```